# How to force cordova app using chrome webview?

Tags: cordova, webview

I completed wrap game with cordova but I have headache with it now, my app use function requestAnimationFrame which Android default webview don't support it. However, chrome of android make it well. It is so good if I can force cordova to execute app under chrome webview...

ps: I included file requestAnimationFrame polyfill of author Paul Irish, you have any alternative?